# How do I fix my problem excluding 0s in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, average

I am trying to exclude 0 in my average code. The code is supposed to ask the user to write 4 numbers and then output an average between them 4.

The code works fine, but now I want to exclude 0s from the code, and it worked but only if you digit 0 one time. For example: I want to exclude two 0s but I have no idea how to do it. My idea was to delete the `num` that has 0 in it so the operation calculates the `0\>` numbers only. There is my code:

```
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("first number: "),10);
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("second number: "),10);
var num3 = parseInt(prompt("third number: "),10);
var num4 = parseInt(prompt("fourth number: "),10);
  
  
if (num1==0){
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = ((num2 + num3+ num4) / 3);  
}
if (num2==0){
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = ((num1 + num3+ num4) / 3);  
}
if (num3==0){
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = ((num1 + num2+ num4) / 3);  
}
  
if (num4==0){
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = ((num1 + num2+ num3) / 3);  
}
else {
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = ((num1 + num2 + num3+ num4) / 4);  
}
```

Comment: The first 3 `if` statements don't do anything, since the `else` only applies to the third if, and will overwrite the result no matter what. You probably want to replace your `if` with `else if` in all 3 places.

Comment: I would start by refactoring the code to use an array of values that can be filtered and counted. Rather than attempt to test for every possible combination.

Answer (score 2):

Think about your current line of thought.

You wrote some code that averages between 3 numbers if one of the 4 numbers is zero. Now you realize it doesn't work when 2 of the 4 numbers are zeroes. How many more `if-else`s would you need to write to accommodate that? Then imagine if 3 of them were zeroes.

This problem is pretty simple because you only take 4 inputs. Now imagine if you took 100 inputs and are trying to get averages of all the non-zero integers from there.

A much more scalable solution would be to have it be such that no matter how many inputs you take, the code will only look at and average the non-zero integers. Something like this:

```js
let num1 = 3; //imagine it were equivalent to var num1 = parseInt(prompt("first number: "),10);
let num2 = 4; //imagine it were equivalent to var num2 = parseInt(prompt("second number: "),10);
let num3 = 0; //imagine it were equivalent to var num3 = parseInt(prompt("third number: "),10);
let num4 = 0; //imagine it were equivalent to var num4 = parseInt(prompt("fourth number: "),10);

const numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4]

function avgNonZeroValues(nums){
  const nonZeros = nums.filter(number => number !== 0);
  const avgOfNonZeros = nonZeros.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
    0
  )/nonZeros.length;
  
  return avgOfNonZeros;
}

console.log(avgNonZeroValues(numbers));
```

You need to know two functions:

1. [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Reduce is a very handy method to go through a list/array and do something with it. It takes in a initial value(0 for us), and we also tell it what to do with every element. Here, we are saying "keep on adding the elements. Here, we are using it to get the sum of all the numbers in the array.

2. [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Filter is pretty self-explanatory. You give this function an array and a condition, and it will filter **out** the elements that do not satisfy the condition, and will give you a new array of all the elements that do satisfy the condition. Here, we are using it to filter all the zeros out of the array.

You give this function `avgNonZeroValues` an array of any length containing numbers, it will remove all the `0`s and average the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring this to use arrays allows easy use of array functions to filter and transform the numbers.

```js
const prompts = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

const values = prompts
  .map(p => parseInt(prompt(`${p} number: `),10))
  .filter(v => v !== 0);

const total = values.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
const avg = total/values.length;

console.log(total, avg);
```